# Consulta com Hibernate erro could not get a field value by reflection

Tags: hibernate

Possuo duas entidades: Profissao e Especialidade. Quando eu selecionar a profissão, gostaria que ele me retornasse todas as especialidades que aquela determinada profissão possui.
Quando mando fazer a busca ele me gera o erro:

```
    Advertência:   #{administradorBean.selecionarProfissao()}: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of modelo.Profissao.idProfissao
javax.faces.FacesException: #{administradorBean.selecionarProfissao()}: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of modelo.Profissao.idProfissao
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of modelo.Profissao.idProfissao
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of modelo.Profissao.idProfissao
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4740)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4459)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:510)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:613)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1861)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2551)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1260)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at DAO.ProfissaoDAO.carregarEspecialidade(ProfissaoDAO.java:56)
    at bean.AdministradorBean.selecionarProfissao(AdministradorBean.java:173)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Integer field modelo.Profissao.idProfissao to java.lang.Integer
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:57)
    ... 73 more

Grave:   javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of modelo.Profissao.idProfissao
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of modelo.Profissao.idProfissao
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4740)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4459)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:510)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:613)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1861)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2551)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1260)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at DAO.ProfissaoDAO.carregarEspecialidade(ProfissaoDAO.java:56)
    at bean.AdministradorBean.selecionarProfissao(AdministradorBean.java:173)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Integer field modelo.Profissao.idProfissao to java.lang.Integer
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:57)
    ... 73 more
```

Classe Profissao

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "profissao")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Profissao.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Profissao p")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Profissao.findByIdProfissao", query = "SELECT p FROM Profissao p WHERE p.idProfissao = :idProfissao")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Profissao.findByNomeProfissao", query = "SELECT p FROM Profissao p WHERE p.nomeProfissao = :nomeProfissao")})
public class Profissao implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idProfissao")
    private Integer idProfissao;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "nomeProfissao")
    private String nomeProfissao;
    @JoinTable(name = "profissional_has_profissao", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "Profissao_idProfissao", referencedColumnName = "idProfissao")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "Profissional_idProfissional", referencedColumnName = "idProfissional")})
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Profissional> profissionalList;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idProfissao")
    private List<Especialidade> especialidadeList;

    public Profissao() {
    }

    public Profissao(Integer idProfissao) {
        this.idProfissao = idProfissao;
    }

    public Integer getIdProfissao() {
        return idProfissao;
    }

    public void setIdProfissao(Integer idProfissao) {
        this.idProfissao = idProfissao;
    }

    public String getNomeProfissao() {
        return nomeProfissao;
    }

    public void setNomeProfissao(String nomeProfissao) {
        this.nomeProfissao = nomeProfissao;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Profissional> getProfissionalList() {
        return profissionalList;
    }

    public void setProfissionalList(List<Profissional> profissionalList) {
        this.profissionalList = profissionalList;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Especialidade> getEspecialidadeList() {
        return especialidadeList;
    }

    public void setEspecialidadeList(List<Especialidade> especialidadeList) {
        this.especialidadeList = especialidadeList;
    }
```

Classe Especialidade

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "especialidade")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Especialidade.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM Especialidade e")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Especialidade.findByIdEspecialidade", query = "SELECT e FROM Especialidade e WHERE e.idEspecialidade = :idEspecialidade")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Especialidade.findByTipoEspecialidade", query = "SELECT e FROM Especialidade e WHERE e.tipoEspecialidade = :tipoEspecialidade")})
public class Especialidade implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idEspecialidade")
    private Integer idEspecialidade;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "tipoEspecialidade")
    private String tipoEspecialidade;
    @JoinColumn(name = "idProfissao", referencedColumnName = "idProfissao")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Profissao idProfissao;

    public Especialidade() {
    }

    public Especialidade(Integer idEspecialidade) {
        this.idEspecialidade = idEspecialidade;
    }

    public Integer getIdEspecialidade() {
        return idEspecialidade;
    }

    public void setIdEspecialidade(Integer idEspecialidade) {
        this.idEspecialidade = idEspecialidade;
    }

    public String getTipoEspecialidade() {
        return tipoEspecialidade;
    }

    public void setTipoEspecialidade(String tipoEspecialidade) {
        this.tipoEspecialidade = tipoEspecialidade;
    }

    public Profissao getIdProfissao() {
        return idProfissao;
    }

    public void setIdProfissao(Profissao idProfissao) {
        this.idProfissao = idProfissao;
    }
```

ProfissaoDAO

```
public List<Especialidade> carregarEspecialidade(Profissao profissao){
    List<Especialidade> listaEspecialidade;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    String sql = "from Especialidade e WHERE e.idProfissao like :id";
    listaEspecialidade = session.createQuery(sql).setParameter("id", profissao.getIdProfissao()).list();
    session.close();

    return listaEspecialidade;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei conseguindo resolver da seguinte maneira:

```
public List<Especialidade> carregarEspecialidade(Profissao profissao){
        List<Especialidade> listaEspecialidade;
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        String sql = "from Especialidade e WHERE e.idProfissao.id = :id"; // adicionado o .id para retornar o id
        listaEspecialidade = session.createQuery(sql).setParameter("id", profissao.getIdProfissao()).list();
        session.close();

        return listaEspecialidade;
    }
```

Qualquer dúvida, só consultar: 
http://www.mograblog.com/2010/09/javax-persistence-persistence-exception-org-hibernate-property-access-exception-could-not-get-a-field-value-by-reflection-getter.html

Answer (score 0):

Tente mudar o setParameter de ProfissaoDAO para:

```
String sql = "from Especialidade e WHERE e.idProfissao = :id";
listaEspecialidade = session.createQuery(sql).setParameter("id", profissao).list();
```

Comment: Opa Marcus, tentei mas continua a dá erro: javax.el.ELException: /admin.xhtml @56,88 value="#{administradorBean.listaEspecialidade}": org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: modelo.Profissao

Comment: Vc setou algo na instância Profissao? Ele está dizendo que algo dessa entidade não foi persistido no BD.

Comment: Desculpe, fiz uma alteração no seu sql tb. Tente novamente, por favor.